# How to find specific words in Trie

Tags: java

I want to find some 3 letters words that start with A and end with E in this type of expression: 
A?E

My program is a dictionary and I am using this code:

```
    public ArrayList<String> Search(String word){

    Node current = root;
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    while(current != null){
        String st = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
            if(current.SubNode(word.charAt(i)) != null) {
                current = current.SubNode(word.charAt(i));
                st+= current;
            }
            if(word.charAt(i) == '?'){
                current = current.SubNode(word.charAt(i));
                st+= current;
            }
        }
        if (current.prefixes == true)
            result.add(st);
    }
    return result;
}
```

But it does not work

Comment: Why don't you use a regular expression? It would be much cleaner.

Comment: I don't know what should I do?!

Answer (score 0):

Here is example how to find it using Regex. Just iterate trough your collection.

```
String input = "AoE";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(A*.*E)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("m.length() = " + m.group().length());
        if (m.group().length() == 3){
            System.out.println("Found a " + m.group() + ".");
        }
    }
```